# Show that $S$ is a subspace iff $u+r\cdot v \in S$ for all $u,v \in V$ and $r \in \Bbb F$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

Let $S$ be a subset of a vector space $V$ over a field $\Bbb F$. Show that $S$ is a subspace iff $u+r\cdot v \in S$ for all $u,v \in V$ and $r \in \Bbb F$.

For the right direction i.e. "if" conditions:
Since $S$ is a subspace of $V$ over a field $\Bbb F$, then the vector addition and scalar multiplication in $V$ are holds in $S$. On the otherhand, the ten axioms of vector spaces are holds in $S$. Hence, $u+v \in S$ and $r \cdot v \in S$ for all $u,v \in S$ and for all $r \in \Bbb F$. Thus, $u+r \cdot v \in S$.

For the left direction i.e. "only if" conditions: Let $u,v \in S$ and $r \in \Bbb F$ with $u+r\cdot v \in S$. Since $u$ and $u+r\cdot v$ both are in $S$, then $r \cdot v$ also in $S$. Since $S$ is a subset of $V$, it suffices to show that the additive identity and additive invers exists in $S$. Since $S \ne \emptyset$, then $0 \cdot v = o \in S$, where $o$ is the zero vector in $V$. Next, $(-1) \cdot v = -v \in S$. Hence, $S$ is a subspace.

Am I true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$S$ is a subspace of $V$ if $S\neq \emptyset$ and $qu+rv\in S$ for each $u, v\in S$, $q, r\in \Bbb F$

With this in mind, $(\implies)$ is trivial, it is the case when $(q, r) =(1, r)$.

For $(\Leftarrow)$, set $v=u$, the condition $u, v\in S \implies u+rv\in S$ therefore gives $(1+r)u\in S$ for each $r\in \Bbb F$. In other words $qu\in S$ for each $q\in \Bbb F$. Then, applying the condition again we see $u, v\in S \implies qu+rv\in S$ is met.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119365/discussion-on-answer-by-rhys-hughes-show-that-s-is-a-subspace-iff-ur-cdot-v).